# Azure - VM Generalize

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I write this question because I found only partial informations about my scenario.

In Azure to clone a VM, I need to deallocate and generalize, after I can create a lot of copy as many I would. The details that I didn't find are:

- the VM generalized "cost" me in term of CORE ? After `azure vm generalize` , If I run `azure vm list-usage` the number of cores used decreased or not ?
- if I generalize a VM with all users / groups / services configured (Apache, DB, etc.) in the same disk of VM, after generalize -> clone, I will find again this configurations in new cloned VMs ?
- what are the parameters that I can change after generalization, ex. Availability Set, Network Security Group, Nic associated, etc. ?

Thanks

Comment: Accept the answer that works, don't edit it into your question.

Comment: Ok, Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the VM generalized "cost" me in term of CORE ? If I run azure vm list-usage the number of cores used decreased or not ?

Yes, it costs you in the term of CORE. However, you don't need pay for the VM. You only need pay for the OS and date VHDs storage account. When you use `vm list-usage`, you will find the core `CurrentValue` does not change. When you delete the VM, the cores will be released.

> I will find again this configurations in new cloned VMs

Yes, you could. Sysprep removes all your personal account information, among other things, and prepares the machine to be used as an image. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-generalize-vhd?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2fwindows%2ftoc.json). For a Linux VM, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image).

> what are the parameters that I can change after generalization, ex.
>   Availability Set, Network Security Group, Nic associated, etc. ?

You could use the `generalized VHD image` to create any VMs. All of them you could associate to the new VM. More information about how to create a VM from a generalized VHD image please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-create-vm-generalized).

Comment: Thanks, I use a Linux VM, I think that I cannot use SysPrep.

Seem that my only chance is create a template from a vm generalized and customize it until the last usage of this template.

Comment: I apologize. I didn't specify before the vm OS system.

Comment: @GiorgioDesideri For a Linux, you should use `sudo waagent -deprovision+user`, this command is similar to `Sysprep`. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image). This command also removes your personal account information.

Comment: [At] Walter "remove your personal information" this is the point. What information remove ? inside user /home there is all the services and codes that I need.

Comment: @GiorgioDesideri When you execute `sudo waagent -deprovision+user
` you will get the warnings `WARNING! The waagent service will be stopped.
WARNING! Cached DHCP leases will be deleted.
WARNING! root password will be disabled. You will not be able to login as root.
WARNING! /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail and /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original will be deleted.
` So, it does not delete your data on `/home`

Answer (score 0):

1. VM's are billed according to their capacity, not on the basis of whether they are generalized or not, a vm and a vm created from generalized vm would cost the same (granted they are the same "size").
2. this question has nothing to do with azure, it's just a [syprep](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940(v=ws.10).aspx). Azure adds nothing to this process.
3. Anything you would expect when creating a new VM.

you need to understand the basic concepts behind virtualization to understand what is going on there.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization